# Sum of arithmetic progression formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

The question that is asked is to find the series described, and than calculate the sum of the first n terms.

Now I have done some research and I found a formula I thought might work, which is 
$$ s_n = \frac{n}{2}(2a_1 + (n-1)d)$$
where the series is of the form 
$a_n = a_1 + (n - 1)d$

Now I have got the following series:
$ 1 + 5 + 9 + 13$ $+$ $...$

This is what I though to be $s_n$, so that $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 5$, etc.
I found the series description: $a_n = a_1 + 4(n-1)$

So I think $a_1 = 1$ and $d = 4$.

When I substitute these values in the formula I get:

$$ s_n = \frac{n}{2} (2 + 4n - 4) $$
$$ s_n = \frac{2n + 4n^2 - 4n}{2} $$
$$ s_n = 2n^2 - 2n $$

Yet, when I check the solution to the problem, it is expected to be 
$$ s_n = n(2n - 1)$$
$$ s_n = 2n^2 - n$$

I can't seem to figure out why I have almost the same result, yet a small difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a little mistake $\frac{-2n}{2}=-n$, and not $-2n$ as you have typed

Comment: Oh, that's also the problem I see :D, stupid me. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

@Adola answered, but I am adding a little trick to find the sum.

In an arithmetic series, the average of the terms equals the average of the extreme terms, by linearity.

For the first four terms,

$$\frac{\text{sum}}4=\frac{1+13}2.$$

For $n$ terms,

$$\frac{\text{sum}}n=\frac{1+1+4(n-1)}2.$$

Comment: This is very helpful! Thanks!